# Why expdp does not include identified by statement?

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

I have the following error when I do a impdp (from a pdb in a 12c to 11g. I also used the parameter version=11.2.0)

IMPDP LOG:

```
ORA-01938: IDENTIFIED BY must be specified for CREATE USER
Failing sql is:
 CREATE USER "BRELELE" DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
```

But when I've created the user I gave a password for

```
create user BRELELE identified by manager default tab....
```

Why is this happeninng?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in 11.2.0.1 which is fixed in the 11.2.0.2 patch set. You should patch the database - or even better upgrade to a version that is supported.

You could create the user in advance before doing the import.

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! I suggest to extend your answer with some links as references.